# XCode 13 warning: Building targets in manual order is deprecated - check "Parallelize build for command-line builds" but no such UI option existst?

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, macos-big-sur, xcode13

I have a product building in Big Sur with Xcode 13 from the commandline via `xcodebuild` and generates this warning:

```
warning: Building targets in manual order is deprecated - check "Parallelize build for command-line builds" in the project editor, or set DISABLE_MANUAL_TARGET_ORDER_BUILD_WARNING in any of the targets in the current build to suppress this warning
```

Documentation says:

[image]

However, there is no such option that I can find:

[image]

Comment: What exactly are the parameters you pass to `xcodebuild`? Perhaps you are including some configuration or an environment variable that is affecting the build?

Comment: `xcodebuild -project MyProject.xcodeproj -alltargets SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/tmp/$APP_NAME Release`

Answer (score 11):

In Xcode 13, the "Parallelize Build" checkbox was replaced with two radio buttons: "Dependency Order" (the same as a checked old checkbox) and "Manual Order" (the same as an unchecked old checkbox).

I think it's a good change because the checkbox didn't give a clear picture of what's going to happen when it's unchecked.

On your screenshot, the "Dependency Order" is already selected, so you should be good to go.

Comment: The screenshot shows my current settings but it still generates the warning. I guess the error should just be ignored.

Comment: Could it be so that you have more than one scheme in your project and the other scheme with a different setting triggers the warning?

Comment: I went through xcoode and all schemes are marked as above.

Comment: This fix did not help me, the error is still there..

Answer (score 5):

This setting is under `Project -> Configurations`:

[image]